# How to include template (with CSS) onto a template which is being rendered?

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

I am relatively new to Jinja and templating and have been struggling to get this sorted for some time now..
Here's my layout of folders:

templates

- base
- content
- form

styles

- newstyle

I have a base template with blockhead/block sidebar/**block content**/**block form** layout. I extend it to my **content template** which has lots of HTML notes I have collected under the **block content**. This has then been extended to form template which is a dynamic block and takes user inputs to login and post comments. All this should be viewed on the same web page, when I render form.html using jinja_env.get_template(template) along with args.
But its not working.

Either I see only my sidebar and form block or I see only my content but never all the three...

I tried to 'include' base onto content template and include content onto form but this messes up the CSS.

Can anyone help??

Also I am a bit confused about to use dynaminc links using url_for which I came across in one of stackoverflow questions ?? Which Template should this be used in??

Answer (score 0):

You can use flask, and put your css stylesheet in a folder named "static", at the root of your project. Call this file "style.css".